# Changes in Source Files Other Than the First Not Triggering Recompilation in Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I'm encountering a problem with my Makefile in a C project, where changes in source files, except for the first file listed in my SRC variable, are not triggering a recompilation. I have a typical setup with source files, object files, and dependency files, and I use a standard pattern for my rules in the Makefile.

The Problem:

When I modify any source file other than main.c and run make, these changes are not detected, and the recompilation does not happen. This is despite having all object files and dependency files correctly generated in my objs folder. For example, if I modify main.c, make correctly detects the change and recompiles it. However, modifying any other file like utils.c or geometry.c does not trigger a recompilation.

Here's a snippet of my Makefile for reference:

```
SRC =   $(SRCDIR)main.c \
        $(SRCDIR)utils.c \
        $(SRCDIR)geomtery.c \
        ... (other source files) ...

OBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)%.c=$(OBJDIR)%.o)
DEP = $(OBJ:.o=.d)
-include $(DEP)

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 # -g -g3 -fsanitize=address
LFLAGS = -lm -lft -lmlx -framework OpenGL -framework AppKit
DEP_FLAGS = -MMD -MP


all: start_compilation $(NAME) end_compilation

start_compilation:
    @printf "\n$(YELLOW)Compiling...$(WHITE)\n"

end_compilation:
    @printf "$(GREEN)Compilation succesfull!$(WHITE)\n"

$(OBJDIR)%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.c
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEP_FLAGS) -I $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
    
$(NAME): $(OBJ) $(LIBFT) $(MLX)
    @printf "\n$(CYAN)Generating project executable...$(WHITE)\n"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJ) -L $(LFT_PATH) -L $(MLX_PATH) -o $(NAME)
```

What I've Tried:

- Verified that .d files are generated for each .c file and they include the correct dependencies.
- Checked the timestamps of the .o and .d files to ensure they are updated on modification.
- Experimented with different orderings of the source files in SRC, but the issue persists regardless of the order.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing in my Makefile configuration that causes this behavior. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can spot a potential mistake in my setup? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make will always build the first explicit target found in the makefile, by default.

You are putting your `include` at the beginning of the file:

```
-include $(DEP)
  ...
all:
```

that means that unless you specify a particular target (by running `make all` for example), it will build the first target found in any of the included files.  This is probably not what you want.

I should also say, this:

```
all: start_compilation $(NAME) end_compilation
```

is not likely to work correctly if you run with parallel builds.  You can't "order" targets to be built using prerequisites in general.  It only happens to work because make will build things in a specific order, and if you use `-j1` (serial) build mode you are sure that the previous prerequisites are done before the next one starts.

Comment: If you want to enforce order, you can create a chain of dependencies such as: `all: end_compilation`, `end_compilation: $(NAME)`, and `$(NAME): start_compilation`.

Comment: Thank you. I've modified the way rules are structured in my Makefile to enforce their execution order. However, I encountered an issue with the placement of `-include $(DEP)`. Depending on its position, it either checks only the first source file, as mentioned, or it causes all source files to recompile, even if they haven't been modified.

What's the best practice in this context for creating a directory that contains both object files and `.d` files without triggering a relink (i.e., without recompiling unmodified files)? That's the outcome I'm aiming for. Thank you.

Comment: `all` should be the first target.  All other ordering of targets is irrelevant.  If you see things being rebuilt when you don't think they should be then something is wrong with the makefile.  The portion of the makefile you show above seems OK, so most likely it's something else.  You can run `make --trace` to get make to tell you why it decided to rebuild targets.